# Python: Multiple conditions -in a pattern- for if/while

Tags: python, design-patterns, while-loop, conditional-statements

Below is a loop to find smallest common multiple of the numbers 1-20:

```
count=0

while not all(count % 1 == 0,  count % 2 == 0,
              count % 3 == 0,  count % 4 == 0,
                ...            count % 20 ==0):
     count+=1

print count
```

It's quite tedious to type out so many conditions. This needs improvement, especially if the number is bigger than 20. However, being new to python, my knee-jerk reaction was:

```
while not all(count % range(1,21)==0):
```

...which doesn't work because python can't read minds. I've thought about putting a list inside the all(), but I'm not sure how to generate a list with variables in it.

.

Is there a shorthand to input a pattern of conditions like these, or is there a smarter way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Generator expressions:

```
while not all(count % i == 0 for i in range(1,21)):
```

Incidentally, this is pretty easy to work out by hand if you factorize the numbers 1..20 into prime factors. It's on the order of 200 million so the loop might take a while.

Comment: It just prints '0' I substitute your line into the above code.

Comment: @user3123966: `count` should start at `1`.

Comment: @Blender it doesn't print anything at all if I start with count = 1 :S

Comment: @user3123966: Your solution is really inefficient, so it'll take a long, long time. Try it with a much smaller number like 10.

Comment: Like I said, it's not very fast. I started it off at 200,000,000 and it still took longer than I was willing to wait. Yours might print something in a year or so. (Python isn't really good at such number crunching. In C I'd expect it to run in a second...)

Answer (score 2):

Use a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
while not all(count % x == 0 for x in range(1,21)):
```

You could also use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) here:

```
while any(count % x for x in range(1,21)):
```

since `0` evaluates to `False` in Python.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution to [your current problem](http://oeis.org/A003418) is to use a useful property of the least common multiple function (assuming you implemented it correctly):

```
lcm(a, b, c) == lcm(lcm(a, b), c)
```

It runs pretty quickly, even for fairly large inputs (the least common multiple of the first 20,000 numbers has 8,676 digits):

```
>>> %timeit reduce(lcm, range(1, 20001))
1 loops, best of 3: 240 ms per loop
```

Comment: This still depends on a useful implementation of `lcm` for two numbers. If you try it with the OP's current implementation, it'll only make it even slower.

Comment: @user2357112: I think that's a valid assumption. Euclid's algorithm is outlined in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Yeah, but you didn't provide a 2-integer algorithm or a link to one. Trying to apply this directly to the OP's code is useless; this is only half an answer.